# Please tell me why dialog flow responses are sometimes not returned for a temporary period of time

Tags: dialogflow-es

every one.

Recently, on rare occasions, Dialogflow does not return a response.

Is there any possible cause for this?
I am currently using Dialogflow SE trial Edition for my plan.

I checked the access log and found that the maximum number of requests is 182 per hour,
so I think there is no problem, because the site says that SE has a limit of 600 requests per minute.

If you have had any experiences like this
I would appreciate it if you could let me know.